# Using JSDoc to extend a generic type

Tags: jsdoc

I'm attempting to satisfy the `[T] extends [Ref<any>]` part of vue's existing Ref object by providing my own object template definition.  This is about as close as I can get:

```js
/**
 * @template {import('vue').Ref} Ref
 * @template {{arg: number}} T
 * @extends {Ref<T>} ref
 * @type {ref} current
 */
export const current = ref({arg: 1})
```

two errors:
[image]

The tooltip error for **ref** is `JSDoc '@extends' is not attached to a class.ts(8022)`

The tooltip error for **current** is `Type 'Ref<{ arg: number; }>' is not assignable to type '{ <T extends object>(value: T): [T] extends [Ref<any>] ? T : Ref<UnwrapRef<T>>; <T>(value: T): Ref<UnwrapRef<T>>; <T = any>(): Ref<T>; }'. Type 'Ref<{ arg: number; }>' provides no match for the signature '<T extends object>(value: T): [T] extends [Ref<any>] ? T : Ref<UnwrapRef<T>>'.ts(2322)` where it seams hopeful **`Ref<{ arg: number; }>`** but does not satisfy is **`[T] extends [Ref<any>]`**.

I started using **`@extends`** because I had an error using just `@type {Ref<T>} current` that said `Type 'Ref' is not generic.ts(2315)`

Vue's Ref type is:

```
export declare interface Ref<T = any> {
    value: T;
    /**
     * Type differentiator only.
     * We need this to be in public d.ts but don't want it to show up in IDE
     * autocomplete, so we use a private Symbol instead.
     */
    [RefSymbol]: true;
    /* Excluded from this release type: dep */
    /* Excluded from this release type: __v_isRef */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.  Also, rather than using a very short name like `T`, the typedef is more global for that file so a specific name was better.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{arg: Number}} currentType
 * @type {import('vue').Ref<currentType>}
 */
 export const current = ref({arg: 1})
```